# this getting converted into object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to write a small function which gets a div element from the html, hides it, assigns a value and a variable name and then parse it into the function to check if the month assigned (the value) is equal equal to the current month. The reason I think its not working is that the 'this' is being converted into an object Object and its not storing the value of the variable that im parsing into it.

```
var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;
var valentinesdiv = $('#valentinesmenu');
$(valentinesdiv).hide();
valentinesdiv = 5;
$.fn.datechecker1 = function () {
    if ($(this) == currentMonth) {
        this.show();
    } else {
        alert(this);
    }
};
$(valentinesdiv).datechecker1();
```

It just goes straight to the alert box and outputs object Object so its not holding the value of the variable as I parse it in.

Comment: Logic here is a mess. Please show corresponding html. What are you thinking `this` should be? ALso, what are your full expectations for this code?

Comment: I'm really confused about what you're trying to do here `valentinesdiv = 5;`. Your reassigning you reference to your `div` to be a `integer`, and the calling datechecker on it? You seem to be using the same variable for a lot of different purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are giving the variable `valentinesdiv` a new value.  When you do that it forgets the reference to the `$("valentinesmenu")`, and when you use it later, you are actually doing this:

```js
$(5).datechecker1();
```

Here is a way you can do what you want ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r2k759g/)):

```js
var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;

var valentinesdiv = $('#valentinesmenu');
$(valentinesdiv).hide();

$.fn.datechecker1 = function(compare) {
    if(compare == currentMonth){
        $(this).show();
    } else {
        alert(this);
    }
};

valentinesdiv.datechecker1(5);
```

Comment: Your alert will still say `object Object`

Comment: no practical reason to ever create a plugin on `$.fn` that just takes in a number not a DOM selector.

Answer (score 2):

A couple issues I see are that you're trying to use the jQuery `show()` on a pure JS `this` object, and you're seeing `Object object` in your alert box because `alert(this)` is literally passing in the object rather than a certain value inside the object.

What you most likely want is here:

```
var element = $(this), value = element.val();
if(value == currentMonth){
  element.show();
} else {
  alert(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`js` below assumes that implementation is to set a variable `x`: `5` at a specific `element`: `#valentinesmenu` ; then check if the variable is equal to variable `currentMonth` .

`x`: `5` is set as `text` of `#valentinesmenu` ; `$.fn.datechecker1` checks if the element is is called on has `text` equal to `currentMonth` ;
if true , call `.show()` on `this` element , if not true , log `this.text(), currentMonth, x` to `console`

Not sure if this is the expected result , or requirement; below `js` is based on assumptions above

---

Try utilizing `.text()`

```js
var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth() + 1;
var x = 5; // ?

var valentinesdiv = $("#valentinesmenu");
// set text of `valentinesdiv` to `currentMonth`
valentinesdiv.text(x).hide();

$.fn.datechecker1 = function() {
  // if `this.text() == currentMonth` do stuff
  if (this.text() == currentMonth) {
    this.show();
  } else {
    // else, do other stuff
    console.log(this.text(), currentMonth, x);
  }
};

valentinesdiv.datechecker1();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="valentinesmenu"></div>
```

Comment: what's the point of the snippet, just outputs `5 NaN`. Can't get date from a single integer

Comment: @charlietfl Should output `5` , `4` at `console` ? Not certain understand _"what's the point of the snippet"_  ? Trying to help OP do whatever they are attempting to accomplish ? How could this post be improved ?

Comment: not in firefox...how do you expect to get date by passing `5` to it? Your browser is probably ignoring it and using today's date. Firefox, rightfully so, is parsing invalid date

Comment: @charlietfl See updated post. Set `div` text to `x`. Does this improve answer ?

Comment: personally i think all these answers are going to confuse OP because there are too many assumptions about original intent and not enough was known to provide a proper answer

Comment: @charlietfl Fair enough. What is appropriate action, non-action under circumstance ? Ask for clarification at comments ? Do not post possible solution ?; which may, may not be able to be interpreted by OP ? Again, only hope to help OP. Is `js` at possible solution above more confusing than `js` at OP ?

Comment: Would add your assumptions to answer, make note that not enough was known and that question was lacking detail

Comment: @charlietfl Added context , explaination to answer.  Does updated post provide an adequate notation of assumptions that went into answer; or if answer should simply be withdrawn for lack of clarity as to requirement , expected results ?

Comment: @charlietfl Does there exist a guide on how to answer an SO question ? How _not_ to answer an SO question ? What essential portions to include in answer ?

Comment: probably if you sift through Help and meta sites. I was only throwing in my opinion so take that with a grain of salt. Opinion was based a lot on what original code looked like though, so OP likely at very beginner level